# PHP file write with a new line

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm making a chat room with a text file. Very simple, but I don't want it to put a damper on the server. Anyways. When I try to make a message, it puts the appended message on the same line like this

```
Alan,5/6/12,message<br>Joe,5/6/12,hello<br>
```

I'd like it to be

```
Alan,5/6/12,message
Joe,5/6/12,hello
```

This is what I have.

```
$total = 'Alan,5/6/12,hello joe<br>\r\n';
$fn = "messages.txt";
$file = fopen($fn,"a");
fwrite($fn,$total);
fclose($fn);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$total = 'Alan,5/6/12,hello joe<br>\r\n';
```

would have worked if you'd used doublequotes, e.g.

```
$total = "Alan,5/6/12,hello joe<br>\r\n";
         ^--                           ^--
```

single-quoted strings do not interpret metacharacters like linebreak/newline, and all your single-quoted version does is put a literal `r` and `n` character into the output.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware this rule applied to newlines as well. Great to know.

Comment: The only valid metachars in a singlequote string are single quotes and backslashes. Anything else is just passed through as literal chars.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `PHP_EOL` at the end:

```
$total = 'Alan,5/6/12,hello joe<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: +1 this is the correct way, however for reference the given example would work if those were double quotes (since [escaped characters don't work inside single-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php))

Comment: I tried this and it still puts in all in one line. I could split each line again by the "<br>", but I just figured there was a way to do this.

Comment: @AlanPHP One line where? On the page, or in the source?

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're writing a CSV, you can do this simpler:

```
<? //PHP 5.4+
(new \SplFileObject('messages.txt', 'a'))->fputcsv([
  'Alan',  //or $user
  \date('c'), //or other date format
  'message content', //or $message_content
]);
?>
```

Comment: This still does the same thing. All one line.

Comment: Are you opening messages.txt in Notepad? Try a different text editor, like Wordpad.

Comment: The file that outputs the messages.txt needs each line to be a different message.

Comment: You change the parameters to match the message that you want to record, eg "Alan" for his message, "Joe" for his. Same for the message content. Where does $total come from?